# C++ new[] into base class pointer crash on array access

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, polymorphism

When I allocate a single object, this code works fine.  When I try to add array syntax, it segfaults.  Why is this?  My goal here is to hide from the outside world the fact that class c is using b objects internally.  I have posted the program to [codepad](http://codepad.org/DLzw3XQt) for you to play with.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// file 1

class a
{
    public:
        virtual void m() { }
        virtual ~a() { }
};

// file 2

class b : public a
{
    int x;

    public:
        void m() { cout << "b!\n"; }
};

// file 3

class c : public a
{
    a *s;

    public:
        // PROBLEMATIC SECTION
        c() { s = new b[10]; } // s = new b;
        void m() { for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s[i].m(); } // s->m();
        ~c() { delete[] s; } // delete s;
        // END PROBLEMATIC SECTION
};

// file 4

int main(void)
{
    c o;

    o.m();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need more detail. Is this a segfault/access violation (implying you accessed memory you shouldn't have)? Is it heap corruption? What behavior occurs on the crash?

Comment: @Doug T.: I have updated the question and posted a codepad reference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One problem is that the expression `s[i]` uses pointer arithmetic to compute the address of the desired object.  Since `s` is defined as pointer to `a`, the result is correct for an array of `a`s and incorrect for an array of `b`s.  The dynamic binding provided by inheritance only works for methods, nothing else (e.g., no virtual data members, no virtual `sizeof`).  Thus when calling the method `s[i].m()` the `this` pointer gets set to what would be the `i`th `a` object in the array.  But since in actuality the array is one of `b`s, it ends up (sometimes) pointing to somewhere in the middle of an object and you get a segfault (probably when the program tries to access the object's vtable).  You might be able to rectify the problem by virtualizing and overloading `operator[]()`.  (I Didn't think it through to see if it will actually work, though.)

Another problem is the `delete` in the destructor, for similar reasons.  You might be able to virtualize and overload it too.  (Again, just a random idea that popped into my head.  Might not work.)

Of course, casting (as suggested by others) will work too.

Answer (score 9):

Creating an array of 10 `b`'s with `new` and then assigning its address to an `a*` is just asking for trouble.

**Do not treat arrays polymorphically.**

For more information see [**ARR39-CPP. Do not treat arrays polymorphically**](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/ARR39-CPP.+Do+not+treat+arrays+polymorphically), at section [06. Arrays and the STL (ARR)](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/06.+Arrays+and+the+STL+%28ARR%29) of the [CERT C++ Secure Coding Standard](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=637).

Comment: Thank you Ari for your understanding. There was no need to delete your comment, really. Anyway, now I deleted my reply :)

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of type "b" not of type "a" and you are assigning it to a pointer of type a. Polymorphism doesn't transfer to dynamic arrays.

```
 a* s
```

to a

```
 b* s
```

and you will see this start working.

Only not-yet-bound **pointers** can be treated polymorphically. Think about it

```
 a* s = new B(); // works
 //a* is a holder for an address

 a* s = new B[10]
 //a* is a holder for an address
 //at that address are a contiguos block of 10 B objects like so
 // [B0][B2]...[B10] (memory layout)
```

when you iterate over the array using s, think about what is used

```
 s[i]
 //s[i] uses the ith B object from memory. Its of type B. It has no polymorphism. 
 // Thats why you use the . notation to call m() not the -> notation
```

before you converted to an array you just had

```
 a* s = new B();
 s->m();
```

s here is just an address, its not a static object like s[i]. Just the address s can still be dynamically bound. What is at s? Who knows? Something at an address s.

See **Ari**'s great answer below for more information about why this also doesn't make sense in terms of how C style arrays are layed out.

Comment: @Ari, thanks, you're correct. I was thinking that as I was typing it. I more want him to think about what is "used" as opposed to something being "loaded".

Answer (score 1):

Each instance of B contains Both X data member and the "vptr" (pointer to the virtual table).

Each instance of A contain only the "vptr"

Thus ,  sizeof(a) != sizeof(b).

Now when you do this thing : "S = new b[10]" you lay on the memory 10 instances of b in a raw , S (which has the type of a*) is getting the beginning that raw of data.

in C::m() method , you tell the compiler to iterate over an array of "a" (because s has the type of a*) , **BUT** , s is actualy pointing to an array of "b". So when you call s[i] what the compiler actualy do is "s + i * sizeof(a)" , the compiler jumps in units of "a" instead of units of "b" and since a and b doesn't have the same size , you get a lot of mambojumbo.

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out a workaround based on your answers.  It allows me to hide the implementation specifics using a layer of indirection.  It also allows me to mix and match objects in my array.  Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// file 1

class a
{
    public:
        virtual void m() { }
        virtual ~a() { }
};

// file 2

class b : public a
{
    int x;

    public:
        void m() { cout << "b!\n"; }
};

// file 3

class c : public a
{
    a **s;

    public:
        // PROBLEMATIC SECTION
        c() { s = new a* [10]; for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s[i] = new b(); }
        void m() { for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) s[i]->m(); }
        ~c() { for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) delete s[i]; delete[] s; }
        // END PROBLEMATIC SECTION
};

// file 4

int main(void)
{
    c o;

    o.m();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use std::vector<boost::smart_ptr<a> > instead!!

Comment: If the OP insists on using arrays though, this is indeed the correct way to get an array of polymorphic things.