# Why does this code crash at the places mentioned?

Tags: c++, arrays, virtual

Can you please elaborate why this code crashes at the places mentioned? I am a bit stumped on this. I guess that it has got something to do with `sizeof(int)` but I am not so sure. Can anybody explain?

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual void SomeFunction() 
    {
        printf("test base\n");
    }

    int m_j;
};

class Derived : public Base {
public:
   void SomeFunction() 
   {
       printf("test derive\n");
   }

private:
   int m_i;
};

void MyWonderfulCode(Base baseArray[])
{
   baseArray[0].SomeFunction();  //Works fine
   baseArray[1].SomeFunction();  //Crashes because of invalid vfptr
   baseArray[2].SomeFunction();  //Crashes because of invalid vfptr
   baseArray[3].SomeFunction();  //Works fine
   baseArray[4].SomeFunction();  //Crashes because of invalid vfptr
   baseArray[5].SomeFunction();  //Crashes because of invalid vfptr
   baseArray[6].SomeFunction();  //Works fine
   baseArray[7].SomeFunction();  //Crashes because of invalid vfptr
   baseArray[8].SomeFunction();  //Crashes because of invalid vfptr
   baseArray[9].SomeFunction();  //Works fine
}
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
   Derived derivedArray[10];
   MyWonderfulCode(derivedArray);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Very much the same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829700/c-new-into-base-class-pointer-crash-on-array-access

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quote from this FAQ: [Is array of derived same as as array of base?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/proper-inheritance#array-derived-vs-base)

> Derived is larger than Base, the pointer arithmetic done with 2nd object baseArray is
>   incorrect: the compiler uses sizeof(Base) when computing the address
>   for 2nd object, yet the array is an array of Derived, which means
>   the address computed  (and the subsequent invocation of
>   member function f()) isn’t even at the beginning of any object! It’s
>   smack in the middle of a Derived object.

Comment: Accepting your answer because of the excellent link that details the exact problem and its solution.

Comment: Link only answers are now frowned upon, please add the relevant details from the link. Also the link no longer points directly to the topic anymore so it should be updated as well. This shows why link only answers are bad.

Comment: Downvoted. As links brings me to an: "You do not have permission to access the requested file on this server.". Thus useless.

Comment: @rxantos: Edited link and provided a brief explanation.

Answer (score 16):

`sizeof(Derived)` is greater than `sizeof(Base)`. That's the reason.

Generally, indexing an array of `Foo` objects at index `i` works the following way:

```
element_address = array_base_address + i * sizeof(Foo)
```

You can see how this indexing breaks if the array elements are not of expected size. Why it works for some indices is because sometimes the calculated element address points to a valid object in memory (but it's not actually the `i`th object).

Answer (score 13):

Never treat arrays polymorphically. The C++ language does not support that. (See also this [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829700/c-new-into-base-class-pointer-crash-on-array-access).)

Answer (score 9):

Arrays can't be used for storing objects of different types or for treating objects polymorphically - store pointers instead.

Sizes of `Base` and `Derived` are different - the code seeing the `Base[]` array has no means to detect that it's really a `Derived[]` array and just indexes the array incorrectly producing all sorts of undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is called shearing. its where the inherited part of the object is effectively stripped away, which results in the V table pointing to missing functions.

the solution is to use an array of pointers. Try this:

```
void MyWonderfulCode(Base* baseArray)
{
   baseArray[0].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[1].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[2].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[3].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[4].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[5].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[6].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[7].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[8].SomeFunction();  
   baseArray[9].SomeFunction();  
}
int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
   Base* derivedArray[10];

   for( int i = 0; i < 10; ++i ) derivedArray[i] = new Derived;

   MyWonderfulCode(derivedArray);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adrian Grigore answered:

> If you use a std::vector, then there shouldn't be any crash.

then deleted the answer because of a comment:

> Doesn't matter in this case. Would crash the same way.

But Adrian was mostly right - if MyWonderFulCode takes a `vector<Base>` or `vector<Base>&` or `vector<Base>*`, and you try to pass it a `vector<Derived>` or `vector<Derived>*`, then the calling code doesn't compile. Hence, I suppose, it doesn't crash either. It's not possible to convert from one vector type to the other (at least, not without creating a new vector and slicing the derived objects into it).

So compilation failure is what you'd want in this case too, because it's not possible to convert from one array type to the other either. The problem is that C/C++ can't tell the difference between a pointer and an array when passed as a function parameter. Because of the perfectly sensible implicit upcast from `Derived*` to `Base*`, we're lumbered with an implicit upcast from `Derived[]` to `Base[]`, which is almost always broken. In C++ terms, it's a completely unjustified `reinterpret_cast`.

This is among the reasons C++ programmers don't use arrays (unless they have to).

Answer (score 0):

Make your MyWonderfulCode function take an array of Base **pointer** instead of Base itself, then you can use that array polymorphically.