# Why we can't implement polymorphism in C++ without base class pointer or reference?

Tags: c++, oop, compiler-theory

First of all have a look at the following code (in this code shape is the base class and line is the derived class)

```
void drawshapes(shape sarray[],int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i< size; i++)
        sarray[i].draw();
}

main()
{
   line larray[10];
   larray[0]=line(p1,p2);//assuming that we have a point class
   larray[1]=line(p2,p3);
   ..........
   drawshapes(larray,10);
}
```

when we compile this program the draw method of shape would be called at first then program terminates. why it terminates ? why we can not implement polymorphism without base class pointer or reference what is the technical reason for this? what compiler will do if we are trying to implement polymorphism with the array of objects ? please explain in much understandable manner with examples. I will be very thankful.

Comment: looks like a homework for me..and has been asked many time before, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043402/why-this-code-crashes

Comment: @Naveen: you're very strict here; I see a question for the technical reason behind the C++ implementation of polymorphism.  That's something totally different than "why this crashes?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are asking a question and providing a code example that fails but for a different reason. From the wording of your question:

**Why are references/pointers required for polymorphism?**

```
struct base {
   virtual void f();
};
struct derived : public base {
   virtual void f();
};
void call1( base b ) {
   b.f(); // base::f
}
void call2( base &b ) {
   b.f(); // derived::f
}
int main() {
   derived d;
   call1(d);
   call2(d);
}
```

When you use pass-by-value semantics (or store derived elements in a base container) you are creating copies of type `base` of the elements of type `derived`. That is called **slicing**, as it resembles the fact that you have a `derived` object and you *slice/cut* only the `base` subobject from it. In the example, `call1` does not work from the object `d` in main, but rather with a temporary of type `base`, and `base::f` is called.

In the `call2` method you are passing a reference to a `base` object. When the compiler sees `call2(d)` in main it will create a reference to the `base` subobject in `d` and pass it to the function. The function performs the operation on a reference of type `base` that points to an object of type `derived`, and will call `derived::f`. The same happens with pointers, when you get a `base *` into a `derived` object, the object is still `derived`.

**Why can I not pass a container of `derived` pointers to a function taking a container of `base` pointers?**

_Clearly if `derived` are `base`, a container of `derived` *is* a container of `base`.

No. Containers of `derived` are not containers of `base`. That would break the type system. The simplest example of using a container of `derived` as container of `base` objects breaking the type system is below.

```
void f( std::vector<base*> & v )
{
   v.push_back( new base );
   v.push_back( new another_derived );
}
int main() {
   std::vector<derived*> v;
   f( v ); // error!!!
}
```

If the line marked with error was allowed by the language, then it would allow the application to insert elements that are not of type `derived*` into the container, and that would mean lots of trouble...

**But the question was about containers of value types...**

When you have containers of value types, the elements get copied into the container. Inserting an element of type `derived` into a container of type `base` will make a copy of the subobject of type `base` within the `derived` object. That is the same **slicing** than above. Besides that being a language restriction, it is there for a good reason, when you have a container of `base` objects, you have space to hold just `base` elements. You cannot store bigger objects into the same container. Else the compiler would not even know how much space to reserve for each element (what if we later extend with an even-bigger type?).

In other languages it may seem as this is actually allowed (Java), but it is not. The only change is in the syntax. When you have `String array[]` in Java you are actually writting the equivalent of `string *array[]` in C++. All non-primitive types are references in the language, and the fact that you do not add the `*` in the syntax does not mean that the container holds *instances of String*, containers hold *references* into Strings, that are more related to c++ pointers than c++ references.

Answer (score 5):

First: you're mixing two concepts: polymorphism, and value vs. reference semantics.

### Runtime polymorphism

Polymorphism comes in many shapes.  Depending on the runtime you use, other options are available.

An interpreted language (like Ruby, Python, Javascript, ...) allows for 'duck typing': if an object merely *has* a method called `foo`, you can call it.  Typically these languages do garbage collection, so the notion of pointers vs. objects isn't too relevant.

C++ has a different viewpoint: polymorphism is allowed, but in a more strict way.  Enforcing a common base class (which may be abstract) allows the compiler to check the semantics of your code: this way the compiler assures that you really meant the `foo` method which implements the intended interface, and not some mishmash of `foo`s.

This polymorphism is realized through the use of a `virtual` function: a pointer to a function, which may vary amongst implementations.  The caller of `foo` will first have to look up the value of the function pointer, and then jump to that function.

So far for polymorphism.

### Containment

Now for containment: if you create an array of `line` objects in C++, these objects are right next to each other in memory; they're contained *by value*.  When you pass the array to a function, the called function can only receive an array of the same type.  Otherwise, taking a step of `sizeof(shape)` into the array we would end up in the mid of a `line`.

In order to fix that, you can contain the objects 'by reference' - in C++ we use pointers for that.

### Compile-time polymorphism

But there is another way to achieve polymorphic functions: templates.  You *can* write your `drawshapes` function with a template argument that says which type of object you are using:

```
template< typename tShape, size_t N > 
void drawshapes( tShape (&aShapes)[N] ) {
    for( tShape* shape=aShapes; shape != aShapes+N; ++shape ) {
        shape->draw();
    }
}
```

(Note: there are stl functions to simplify this, but that's out of the scope of the question.

```
std::for_each( shapes, shapes+10, mem_fun_ref( &shape::draw ) );
```

)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot pass an array of line instead of an array of shape.
You must use array of pointers.
This happens because when the function tries to access the second member, it does *(sarray + sizeof(shape)) instead of *(sarray + sizeof(line)), that would be the correct way to access the second element of an array of line.

Comment: i am expecting detailed answer, this answer is not helpful.

Comment: This answer is quite helpful, reread it until you understand. An array of `derived` is not an array of `base`, even if each `derived` is a `base`. There is another problem in your code, that is maybe what you are more interested in now, why does polymorphism require reference/pointer... but this answer is quite valuable in itself.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
void drawshapes(shape *sarray[],int size)
{
   for(int i=0;i< size; i++)
      sarray[i]->draw();
}

main()
{
   shape *larray[10];
   larray[0] = new line(p1,p2);//assuming that we have a point class
   larray[1] = new line(p2,p3);
   ..........
   drawshapes(larray, 10);
   // clean-up memory
   ...
}
```