# problems accessing derived class in array

Tags: c++, derived-class

```
class BaseObj
{
public:
    int position;
};

class EnemyObj: public BaseObj
{
public:
    int quantity;
};

class PlayerObj: public BaseObj
{
public:
    int lives;
};

int main()
{
    BaseObj* myObjs[3];

    BaseObj* b = new BaseObj();
    b->position = 1;
    myObjs[0] = b;

    EnemyObj* e = new EnemyObj();
    e->position = 2;
    e->quantity = 5;
    myObjs[1] = e;

    PlayerObj* p = new PlayerObj();
    p->position = 3;
    p->lives = 2;
    myObjs[2] = p;

    myObjs[2]->lives = 2;  // error is here
    return 0;
}
```

my problem is that i want to have an array of all my game objects so i can have them all together, but when i try to access
myObjs[2]->lives
I am unable to do so. This is the error I get:

```
error C2039: 'lives' : is not a member of 'BaseObj'
```

Comment: You shouldn't really use arrays polymorphically. You'd be better to use a std::vector. A fairly good explanation of why can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043402/why-this-code-crashes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is a statically typed language and this means that every variable has a specific type. Your array contains pointers to `BaseObj` and this means that the compiler will only allow access to the members defined in that class.

You can tell the compiler that indeed one of those pointers is pointing to a more specific (i.e. derived) class instance in two ways:

1. `dynamic_cast<PlayerObj*>(p)`

   This expression will return a pointer to `PlayerObj` if indeed `p` was pointing to an instance of that class (or to an instance of a class derived from `PlayerObj`). If this is not the case however the returned pointer will be the null pointer even if `p` was not null.

   To be able to use `dynamic_cast` for a base->derived conversion you must be sure that [Run-Time Type Information (RTTI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) has been enabled if it's not elabled by default for your compiler and that your base class is a "polymorphic type", i.e. it must have at least one virtual method.
2. `static_cast<PlayerObj*>(p)`

   This does the same conversion, however if `p` is not pointing to an instance of `PlayerObj` or of a class derived from `PlayerObj` then you are entering the "undefined behavior" land, exactly like when you write out of an array or use an object after you've `delete`d it. It may mean program crash, crazy behavior, daemons flying off your nose or even worse (e.g. that everything seems to work anyway and the crash will happen one million executed instuctions later).

Often a solution used in many C++ programs is to only use `static_cast` but eventually checking first the type of the pointed to instance by having a "type" data member (e.g. an enum) in the base class. This means that you're basically building your own RTTI instead of using the one provided by the compiler.

Comment: -1..`dynamic_cast` cannot be applied to non-polymorphic type. http://www.ideone.com/tsqRO

Answer (score 4):

[myObjs is a pointer to base so it can access only base members](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/30634/)

Answer (score 2):

`dynamic_cast` is your friend:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class BaseObj {
public:
    BaseObj() : position(-1) {
    }

    virtual ~BaseObj() {
    }

    int position;
};

class EnemyObj : public BaseObj {
public:
    EnemyObj() : quantity(0) {
    }

    virtual ~EnemyObj() {
    }

    int quantity;
};

class PlayerObj : public BaseObj {
public:
    PlayerObj() : lives(9) {
    }

    virtual ~PlayerObj() {
    }

    int lives;
};

int main() {
    BaseObj* myObjs[3];

    BaseObj* b = new BaseObj();

    b->position = 1;
    myObjs[0] = b;

    EnemyObj* e = new EnemyObj();
    e->position = 2;
    e->quantity = 5;
    myObjs[1] = e;

    PlayerObj* p = new PlayerObj();
    p->position = 3;
    p->lives = 2;
    myObjs[2] = p;

    if (PlayerObj * const player = dynamic_cast<PlayerObj*>(myObjs[0])) {
        std::cout << player << "\n";
        player->lives = 2;
    }
    if (PlayerObj * const player = dynamic_cast<PlayerObj*>(myObjs[1])) {
        std::cout << player << "\n";
        player->lives = 2;
    }
    if (PlayerObj * const player = dynamic_cast<PlayerObj*>(myObjs[2])) {
        std::cout << player << "\n";
        player->lives = 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
PlayerObj* player = dynamic_cast<PlayerObj*>(myObjs[2]);
if(player)
{
    player->lives = ...
}
```

or if you are sure that myObjs[2] is of type PlayerObj* you can use:

```
(static_cast<PlayerObj*>(myObjs[2]))->lives = ...
```

Comment: +1 but probably the first method is better since the array contains all kinds of objects it seems.

Comment: -1..`dynamic_cast` cannot be applied to non-polymorphic type. http://www.ideone.com/tsqRO

Comment: @Nawaz Thanks for the tip! I didn't know that. Usually I add my own RTTI and use static_cast.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, thank you all so much for your quick replies! Just jumping back on to let you all know you helped me fix the problem and now it's all working perfectly.

I went with

```
if(myObjs[2].type == PlayerObj)
{
      (static_cast <PlayerObj*>(myObjs[2]))->lives = 0;
}
```

and added an object type enum to the base class to define the type.