# virtual destructor fail using array

Tags: c++, polymorphism, segmentation-fault, new-operator, virtual-destructor

I found this code on a [web site](http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/~gsd/halado_cpp/ch05s04.html)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Base
{
    Base() { cout << "Base" << " "; }
    virtual ~Base() { cout << "~Base" << endl; }

    int i;
};
struct Der : public Base
{
    Der() { cout << "Der" << endl; }
    virtual ~Der() { cout << "~Der" << " "; }

    int it[10]; // sizeof(Base) != sizeof(Der)
};

int main()
{
    Base *bp = new Der;
    Base *bq = new Der[5];

    delete    bp;
    delete [] bq;   // this causes runtime error
}
```

why does it [crash](http://codepad.org/gaW1v1Aq)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Polymorphism & Pointers to arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411844/polymorphism-pointers-to-arrays)

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043402/why-this-code-crashes

Comment: Just use std::vector<Base*> instead of array ...

Comment: Or std::array<Base*> from C++0x...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Base *bq = new Der[5];
delete [] bq;   // this causes runtime error
```

The reason is arrays are not treated *polymorphically*. Therefore, in the above code, the `delete` statement invokes **undefined behaviour**.

§5.3.5/3 C++03 says

> In the first alternative (delete object), if the static type of the operand is different from its dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the operand’s dynamic type and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. **In the second alternative (*delete array*) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.**

You're lucky that it gives runtime-error, and you got the opportunity to know a serious bug in your code, as soon as possible.

Comment: And this appears to be the case still in C++11.  Same section:  5.3.5/3