# Why is derived class destructor not called in clang

Tags: c++, virtual, destructor

Why is the derived destructor not called with clang++ 10, it works as expected with g++ 9?
Why do I get

```
BC 
DC 
BD
```

Instead of

```
BC 
DC 
DD 
BD
```

---

```
struct AA
{
    AA()
    {
        cout <<"BC"<<endl;
    }
    virtual ~AA()
    {
        cout <<"BD"<<endl;
    }    
};
struct AB: public AA
{
    AB()
    {
        cout <<"DC"<<endl;
    }
    ~AB() override
    {
        cout <<"DD"<<endl;
    }

};
    
int main()
{
    AA *x= new AB[1];
    delete [] x;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I made an [MCVE on CompilerExplorer](https://godbolt.org/z/455eWr). (Btw. it seems to be related to the array because for a plain pointer it works in clang as well.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [virtual destructor fail using array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754532/virtual-destructor-fail-using-array) (a dark corner of the language indeed).

Comment: Polymorphism **requires** a pointer (including smart pointers) or a reference.  Array objects do not support polymorphism.  Array of pointer can have polymorphic pointers, but the Array-as-an-object itself is not polymorphic.  A `new AB` is an object, a `new AB[1]` is an array, even though just an "array of one thing".